# Logstash Grok Filter for Mongodb Slow Query

Tags: mongodb, logstash, logstash-grok

I was trying the below grok filter pattern and it works on the [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) but fails when deployed on the logstash.

**Pattern:**

```
'%{GREEDYDATA}:"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}"s":"%{WORD:severity}",%{SPACE}"c":"%{WORD:component}",%{SPACE}"id":%{NUMBER:id},%{SPACE}"ctx":%{QUOTEDSTRING:context},"msg":%{QUOTEDSTRING:msg},"attr":{"remote":"%{IPV4:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:port}","connectionId":%{NUMBER:connection_id},"connectionCount":%{NUMBER:connection_count}%{GREEDYDATA}',
```

**Input:**

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-09T09:51:41.936+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2468512","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.21.41.24:58546","connectionId":2468512,"connectionCount":1617}}
```

LogStash Error:

```
{"level":"ERROR","loggerName":"logstash.agent","timeMillis":1604933044844,"thread":"Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>","logEvent":{"message":"Failed to execute action","action":{"metaClass":{"metaClass":{"metaClass":{"action":"PipelineAction::Create<main>","exception":"LogStash::ConfigurationError","message":"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", [A-Za-z0-9_-], '\"', \"'\", [A-Za-z_], \"-\", [0-9], \"[\", \"{\" at line 26, column 9 (byte 13997) after filter {\n  if [container][image] =~ \"mongodb\" {\n    grok {\n      patterns_dir => [\"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns\"]\n      match => { \"message\" => [\n        '%{GREEDYDATA}:\"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}\"s\":\"%{WORD:severity}\",%{SPACE}\"c\":\"%{WORD:component}\",%{SPACE}\"id\":%{NUMBER:id},%{SPACE}\"ctx\":%{QUOTEDSTRING:context},\"msg\":%{QUOTEDSTRING:msg},\"attr\":{\"remote\":\"%{IPV4:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:port}\",\"connectionId\":%{NUMBER:connection_id},\"connectionCount\":%{NUMBER:connection_count}%{GREEDYDATA}',\n        ","backtrace":["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'","org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:183:in `initialize'","org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'","/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'","/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'","/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:357:in `block in converge_state'"]}}}}}}
```

Here is the conf file I'm using

```
filter {
  if [container][image] =~ "mongodb" {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns"]
      match => { "message" => [
        '%{GREEDYDATA}:"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}"s":"%{WORD:severity}",%{SPACE}"c":"%{WORD:component}",%{SPACE}"id":%{NUMBER:id},%{SPACE}"ctx":%{QUOTEDSTRING:context},"msg":%{QUOTEDSTRING:msg},"attr":{"remote":"%{IPV4:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:port}","connectionId":%{NUMBER:connection_id},"connectionCount":%{NUMBER:connection_count}%{GREEDYDATA}',
        ]
        break_on_match => false
        tag_on_failure => ["failed_match"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if anyone has a way to fix this issue. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Your `grok` filter is missing a closing curly bracket in the `match` option`.

```
grok {
  patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns"]
  match => { "message" => ['%{GREEDYDATA}:"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}"s":"%{WORD:severity}",%{SPACE}"c":"%{WORD:component}",%{SPACE}"id":%{NUMBER:id},%{SPACE}"ctx":%{QUOTEDSTRING:context},"msg":%{QUOTEDSTRING:msg},"attr":{"remote":"%{IPV4:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:port}","connectionId":%{NUMBER:connection_id},"connectionCount":%{NUMBER:connection_count}%{GREEDYDATA}']}
  break_on_match => false
  tag_on_failure => ["failed_match"]
}
```

But your message is already a **json** object, you don't need to use `grok` you can use the `json` [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) to parse the message and the `mutate` [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) to rename the fields after the parse.

Try something like this

```
json {
    source => "message"
}
mutate {
    rename => ["[t][$date]","timestamp"]
    rename => ["s","severity"]
    rename => ["c","component"]
    ... the rest of your fields ...
}
```